# Convert byte[] to ArrayList<String>

Tags: java

I found a question here on SO: [Convert ArrayList<String> to byte []](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618978/convert-arrayliststring-to-byte)

It is about converting `ArrayList<String>` to `byte[]`.

Now is it possible to convert `byte[]` to `ArrayList<String>` ?

Comment: Why would you turn something into an array of bytes if you couldn't convert it back? And I don't know why you've accepted the answer you did. As it will not produce a list of strings equal to that which was used to create the byte array.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is character encoding and why should I bother with it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611455/what-is-character-encoding-and-why-should-i-bother-with-it)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this should suffice, forgive any compile typos I've just rattled it out here:

```
for(int i = 0; i < allbytes.length; i++)
{
    String str = new String(allbytes[i]);
    myarraylist.add(str);
}
```

Comment: Np. Best ask that one as a new question Ali, with more examples of exactly what you're looking to achieve

Comment: @Ali: Do you mean String[] to ArrayList<String> - if so, you can use Arrays.asList

Comment: @SidMalani : No, Just String to ArrayList<String>.

Comment: @Ali Arrays.asList(string.split("")); I am assuming you want to split for each character. It I think will introduce a space in first element which you can easily remove.

Answer (score 8):

Looks like nobody read the original question :)

If you used the method from the first answer to serialize each string separately, doing exactly the opposite will yield the required result:

```
    ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(byte[] yourData);
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bais);
    ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        Object obj = null;

        while ((obj = ois.readObject()) != null) {
            al.add((String) obj);
        }
    } catch (EOFException ex) { //This exception will be caught when EOF is reached
        System.out.println("End of file reached.");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        //Close the ObjectInputStream
        try {
            if (ois != null) {
                ois.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

If your byte[] contains the ArrayList itself, you can do:

```
    ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(byte[] yourData);
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bais);
    try {
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = ( ArrayList<String>) ois.readObject();
        ois.close();
    } catch (EOFException ex) { //This exception will be caught when EOF is reached
        System.out.println("End of file reached.");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        //Close the ObjectInputStream
        try {
            if (ois!= null) {
                ois.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

yeah its possible, take each item from byte array and convert to string, then add to arraylist

```
String str = new String(byte[i]);
arraylist.add(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

it depends very much on the semantics you expect from such a method. The easiest way would be, `new String(bytes, "US-ASCII")`—and then split it into the details you want.

There are obviously some problems:

1. How can we be sure it's `"US-ASCII"` and not `"UTF8"` or, say, `"Cp1251"`?
2. What is the string delimiter?
3. What if we want one of the strings to *contain* a delimiter?

And so on and so forth. But the easiest way is indeed to call `String` constructor—it'll be enough to get you started.